Error running discord.js bot in docker: ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined
There are discord.js bot (below: main.ts, basic logic in modules):
import {Client, GatewayIntentBits, ThreadChannel} from "discord.js";
import {startCommandBuilder} from "./builders/slashCommandBuilders";
import Database from "./classes/databaseClass";
import BotInteraction from "./classes/interactionClass";
import mainEvents from "./events/mainEvents";
import messageEvent from "./events/messageEvent";

export const client = new Client({intents: [
                GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
                GatewayIntentBits.GuildModeration,
                GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
                GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans,
                GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
                GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessagePolls,
                GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
        ]})

const env = process.env

export const mysqlConfig = {
        user: 'bot',
        password: env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        database: env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
        host: env.MYSQL_HOST,
        port: env.MYSQL_PORT
}

client.on('ready', async (event) => {
        if (!event.user) return

        event.user.setStatus("dnd")

        await event.application.commands.create(startCommandBuilder)

        const db = new Database()
        await db.init()

        console.log(`${event.user.displayName} started!`)

})

client.on('interactionCreate', async (event) => {
        const interaction = new BotInteraction(event)

        await mainEvents(interaction)

})

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
        if (!message.member || message.member.user.bot || !(message.channel instanceof ThreadChannel)) return
        await messageEvent(message)
})

client.login(env.BOT_TOKEN)

When I run the bot locally, everything works fine, but when I try to do it in the docker container (in gitlab via pipline), an error occurs:
ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined
     at Object.<anonymous> (/bot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/node_modules/undici/lib/web/fetch/response.js:530:3)
     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
     at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/bot/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1608:43)
     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)
     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/bot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/node_modules/undici/lib/web/fetch/index.js:11:5)
     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
 /bot/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/node_modules/undici/lib/web/fetch/response.js:530
   ReadableStream
   ^

What could make a mistake?
Almost nothing. Most installed pair node_modules

Node version is too old.

Node version is too old, after its upgrade, everything worked
